# Make VSTS SPN owner of AAD AppId

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have a scenario that requires a task running in VSTS add a "Reply URL" to an App registered in AAD.

I've added a service connection in VSTS, it created a SPN and made it a contributor of the Azure subscription, additionally I've added the SPN as an owner of the AppID by calling `Add-AzureADApplicationOwner`
Still the VSTS task can't operate on the AppID, it can't even read it, e.g. running `Get-AzureRmADApplication` I get:

> [error]Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Starian's answer? any update?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to these steps below to grant permission:

1. Log on to the Azure portal
2. Select Azure Active Directory
3. Select App registrations
4. Select the corresponding application
5. Click Settings
6. Click Required permissions
7. Click + Add > Select an API
8. Select Windows Azure Active Directory >Select
9. Check necessary permissions in Select permissions > select.
10. Click Done
11. Click Grant Permissions button

Answer (score 0):

An addition to [starian chen-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6587650/starian-chen-msft)'s answer. I managed to solve the same problem by adding and granting the following permissions on the answer's **Step 9**:

- Read and write directory data
- Manage apps that this app creates or owns

Comment: Be careful with Read and Write Directory Data; this is very open and doesn't follow least privilege patterns.

Comment: @PhilPeters Thank you! I was afraid so too. Do you have any suggestions which less privileged right should I be using?

Comment: Depending one what you're doing I would say limit your write to the directory object you are trying to create (users, groups or applications). For the example in the question where the OP is wanting to read the directory I would only allow this permission: 'Directory.Read.All'